# Queue for two types using 2 queues?

Tags: data-structures, algorithm-design, queues

I'm reading the book Cracking the Code.

The answer for this question suggests a solution using timestamps and two separate queues. This is straightforward and involves simply enqueuing into the appropriate queues. Dequeuing oldest involves checking timestamps of front of both queues and removing the oldest.

I'm wondering if there is a way to do this without using an additional timestamp field.

[image]

My approach is to use two queues, `main` and `backup`

### Enqueue

I simply push into `backup`

### Dequeue Dog/Cat aka. specific type dequeue

I check if front of `main` has this type. If not or if `main` is empty, then I go to `backup`.

If `backup` contains the right type, `dequeue` it

If `backup` does not contain it, then shift from `backup` to `main` i.e. `dequeue` from `backup` and `enqueue` to `main`

### Dequeue oldest pet

`dequeue` from `main` if `main` has elements

If `main` is empty, `dequeue` from `backup`

Comment: I think you are over-complicating it... You just need a `dogs` queue and a `cats` queue, its that simple.

Comment: the whole point of posting this question is to discuss an alternate approach...

Comment: However your idea also uses two queues. I don't understand what you want to ask here then.

Comment: "I'm wondering if there is a way to do this without using an additional timestamp field."

Comment: Why do you need a timestamp for a queue? Also, what is the difference if you assign one "timestamp" for each animal anyways?

Comment: The book's solution uses a timestamp to differentiate between the older animal in the two queues. I'm trying to understand if there is a way to do the same i.e. dequeue specific type, dequeue oldest, enqueue animal, etc. WITHOUT a timestamp field (which the book's solution uses).

Comment: @nirshahar not sure what you mean by "what is the difference." The difference is precisely not using an extra field in the object design. I understand you find the question pointless. I'd like to leave it for the other users. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I think I got what you tried to ask here.

Comment: Do you allow to use more than $2$ queues? Or maybe a modified version of a queue?

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics.  You can [use LaTeX](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands).  Don't forget to give proper attribution to your sources!

Answer (score 2):

Your solution seems to have higher time complexity than needed. If you have $n$ dogs and then $n$ cats then dequeuing all cats will cost you $O(n^2)$ as you need to go through dogs first.

I'd go with three queues: all animals, dogs, cats.

Enqueue: Create an instance of dog/cat, push into all animals queue. Next, push the same instance to the dog/cat queue appropriately.

Dequeue Dog/Cat: just dequeue from dog/cat queue. Do not touch all animals queue.

Dequeue oldest: dequeue from all animals queue. If it's a dog then peek a dog from the dog queue. If those are the same instances - dequeue from dog queue and return. Otherwise discard the dog from the all animals queue and repeat.

Time complexity: each animal is inserted exactly once to each queue and removed exactly once so amortized time is $O(1)$ for enqueue and $O(1)$ for dequeue.